# Django - How to add multiple permissions on group?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a list of permissions

```
list = ['view', 'add', 'edit']
```

The permissions inside the list are already saved on my table.

I first clear the group's previous permission so I can insert a new one

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='Group1')
group.permissions.clear()
```

Is there a way to add the list of permission to Group1 programmatically?

Comment: I hope there must be some ContentType is associated with each permission.

Comment: Try this `group.permissions.set(list)`

Comment: @JPG all permissions on the list is the codename

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I already tried it but it returns an error
```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10```

Comment: won't it be better if you can just have a group whose purpose is doing one of the list, view, and add. for this case, it looks like an "operator" role(or group). and in your view you can use ```request.user.group``` for validation. further you can write permission classes to enhance functionality further.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an app named `blog` and a model named `BlogPost` and want to add permissions `view`, `change`, `add` for that model to the group named `Blogger`, you should be able to do:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

codenames = ['view_blogpost', 'change_blogpost', 'add_blogpost']

group = Group.objects.filter(name='Blogger').first()
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='blog', codename__in=codenames)
for permission in permissions.all():
    group.permissions.add(permission)
```

Note: The check for the `app_label` is probably not necessary, but it ensures that you do not add permissions for a model `BlogPost` from another app, if one exists.

Have a look at tables `auth_permission` and `django_content_type` in your db for the fields and possible values.